# Having set up a DCHP server, what do I need to do for the rest of my network?

Tags: dhcp, arm, embedded-system

I've got a Raspberry Pi arriving *any day now*, and I intend to use it (amongst other things) as a DHCP server.

Currently we have a few devices on our network to which we would like to assign static IPs, and a router, which is currently the DHCP server (the router can assign static IPs, but is buggy as hell, I've never got the config to stick for more than a few hours).

Having connected the Pi to the network and configured `dhcpl-3-server`, what do I need to do on the rest of my network so that it works properly (clients get their IPs from the Pi, and use the Router as the default gateway)?

Comment: @Mitch Should I? What's the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your DHCP configuration on the Raspberry Pi is ok and you don't need any other feature, you shouldn't need anything else. But you have to make sure the Raspberry Pi gives the proper default gw address to the clients, as well as a primary and a secondary DNS server (again the router for the primary, I suppose and I suggest a Google Public DNS server or any other OpenDNS server for the secondary).

This is my old DHCPd configuration, maybe you can find it useful.

```
subnet 192.168.10.0 netmask 255.255.255.0
{
    range 192.168.10.100 192.168.10.200;
    default-lease-time 86400;
    max-lease-time 86400;
    option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
    option broadcast-address 192.168.10.255;
    option routers 192.168.10.1;
    option domain-name-servers 192.168.10.115;
    option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8;
}
```